# Terraform aws_alb behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-alb

In my terraform script I defined a load balancer plus two listeners and two target groups which each have assigned two targets. This all works okay. When any of these defined items is removed manually from within the AWS console they are added again by TF script once it is run again.

The script makes use of these modules:

- aws_alb
- aws_lb_target_group
- aws_lb_listener
- aws_lb_target_group_attachment

But when I manually add a new listener plus a targetgroup with its own targets this change isn't detected by the terraform script I would expect that these manual additions would be removed as they are linked to the aws_alb that is created with TF. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected. Terraform is declarative, you define your infrastructure and it will figure out what the diffs are in order to determine what changes it needs to make. It can only make these changes and diff against resources it controls unless you use `data` sources to look up AWS resources. Manually created resources won't be managed by Terraform, however you can create the Terraform config for them and import if you want to manage them with Terraform (see the docs for [`import`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html))

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand it is declarative. What you define is what you get. But for the aws_alb I was expecting different behavior.

For example when you assign an extra security group to an ec2 instance by hand and you run the TF script again it will be detected and be removed again.

As the listener is 'assigned' to the aws_alb I would expect that the aws_alb object is aware of the listener assigned and detects the diff and with a TF run it should be removed again. But maybe the link aws_alb <> listener works different.

Comment: In the EC2 instance example the security group ids are defined inline in the resource definition for the instance, while in the ALB example a listener is attached to an ALB via a separate standalone resource.